# Apiary API endpoint returning null data when called from web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, apiary.io, apiary

I have a mock API in Apiary where if I hit my endpoint with cURL or just in the browser, it returns:

```
[
{
  "id": 1,
  "user_id": 1,
  "status": "Review"
  "name": "New York Songwriter",
  "negotiable": true,
  "description": "",
  "created_at": "2015-02-09T02:29:58 +08:00",
  "modified_at": "2015-02-17T05:30:17 +08:00"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "user_id": 1,
  "status": "Accepted"
  "name": "Licensing Contract",
  "negotiable": false,
  "description": "Third party licensing agreement",
  "created_at": "2015-02-09T02:29:58 +08:00",
  "modified_at": "2015-02-17T05:30:17 +08:00"
}
]
```

I have a React app where I'm hitting this endpoint with axios in a function that is called in `componentWillMount`:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.loadItems();
  }

  loadItems() {
    var self = this;
    axios({
      url: ENDPOINT,
      method: 'get',
      responseType: 'json'
    })
    .then(function(r) {
      console.log(r);
      var d = r.data;
      self.setState({
        agreements: d
      });
    })
    .catch(function(r) {
      console.log(r);
    });
  }
```

The `console.log` I get a status 200 in the response, but `data` is null.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you try console.log(r.data) ?

Comment: @KobyDouek It returns `null`.

Comment: @CassidyWilliams what does `console.log(r)` return I feel like `console.log(r[0])` will return useful data

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal `console.log(r[0])` returns `undefined` and `console.log(r)` returns `{"data":null,"status":200,"statusText":"OK","headers":{"content-type":"application/json"},"config":{"transformRequest":{},"transformResponse":{},"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"method":"get","url":ENDPOINT ,"responseType":"json"},"request":{}}`

Comment: try to use the alias: `axios.get(url).then(response=> console.log(response, response.data)).catch(error=>console.log(e))`

Comment: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/196

Comment: @MayankShukla this appears to work!!  Why is that?

Comment: @CassidyWilliams the way you were using is the custom way (providing the configuration manually), may be you need to define few more properties, this alias provide all the required configuration, so you don't need to worry about the get configuration, glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mayank Shukla for the answer in the comments. The key is to use the native axios GET method, like so:

```
axios.get(ENDPOINT)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Because the native GET has all the properties built in. In my example I hadn't defined all necessary properties.

Thanks again, Mayank!